# Unique id for blueimp file uploader

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, blueimp

Im using blueimp uploader for file upload things and i have tried to get a unique id for very set of images but i end up getting a unique id for each file upload

i have tried to add it through the handle_file_upload function but each time its calling it and hence getting a new id everytime

any help would be appretiated guys

thanks

Comment: Can you paste some code that you are using for the upload? I'm not sure I understand why you need different ids.

Answer (score 0):

just count with own var. don't use index from function.

```
var i=0; // global!
....
$.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
    $i++;
    $('<p>Here is your ID:' + i+'</p>').appendTo('#container'); // e.g.
    ...
}
```